# Hirefire not run delayed jobs

Tags: hirefire

i'm using delayed job active record with hirefire gem to mange workers. But on heroku it seems like hirefire not running jobs and when i run this command below

```
    heroku run rake jobs:work --app gentle-gorge-9319
```

then it runs job. But hirefire author says that it will detect jobs as itself.

Any help??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't ever scaled up your workers for your app, scale up to a single worker and then back down. Apparently this marks your app as "chargeable" and lets HireFire scale workers up/down. That worked for me.

> If this is the first time you're using Heroku, or have never used any
>   of their paid features, be sure that you've entered your billing
>   information over at Heroku so they can actually charge you for using
>   their resources. If you haven't filled in your billing information
>   then it won't work. Additionally, try manually scale up from Heroku's
>   manager (or via the command line) to see if it works. This also flags
>   you account as “chargeable” which is important as HireFire cannot do
>   this for you.

via [HireFire's FAQs](http://hirefire.io/documentation/support/faqs)